# .NET: IsolatedStorageException

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm building a Windows Phone 7 app in Silverlight. I'm having difficulty with `IsolatedStorage`.

```
        IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (!storage.FileExists(STORIES_FILE))
        {
            storage.CreateFile(STORIES_FILE);
        }

        string contents;

        // fails here
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.OpenFile(STORIES_FILE, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

The exception is:

```
"Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream."
System.Exception {System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException}
```

What could I be doing wrong here? [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190070(v=VS.95).aspx) that this exception is thrown when the isolated storage is removed or disabled. Could that have happened? I'm experiencing this problem on the emulator.

**Update**: This appears to only happen the first time I'm running the app on the emulator. After the app crashes, I run it on the emulator again, and this problem doesn't occur.

**Update 2**: Using `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` instead of `FileMode.Open` appears to have solved the problem.

Comment: I'm using FileMode.OpenOrCreate, but still getting the same issue. The first time it succeeds, but seconds time it fails.

Answer (score 3):

The first time you run your application, the file is not there, try this instead:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.OpenFile(STORIES_FILE, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Comment: But I'm calling `storage.CreateFile(FILE_NAME)`. That doesn't do anything?

Comment: Yeah, but in that piece of code, you didn't use the stream returned by the storage.CreateFile call.  Until THAT instance flushed or closed itself, the file would still not exist.  With the change in the FileMode parameter, you could just remove the call to CreateFile to clean it up.

Comment: So I need something like `storage.CreateFile("Foo").Flush()`?

Comment: You could, but it seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead.  Using the OpenOrCreate enumeration would allow you to remove the entire if block as that check is done for you.